# Using rawQuery to pass _id from listview and populate details of the selection in new activity (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an activity with a listview that is displaying the results of a previous listview.  The two listview activities are:

List of Cities.
List of Streets within that city.

When I select a Street on my ListView, I then want to populate another activity with certain details of the street that are stored in my database (example, restaurants or points of interest).

I am trying to pass the _id of the street that I clicked and get it in my new activity (just like I did with the City to Street activity) but I'm not able to return any results.  Below is my code.  I'd appreciate any assistance in trying to figure this one out.

Here is the piece of my code to get the information from clicking on a specific Street.  To keep it simple, I'm just trying to display an ID and the name again just to get something to populate from the row:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Street_Details.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("Street_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

And here is my code in my new activity to display some details of that street:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.peak_details);

   Intent i = getIntent(); 
   streetId = getIntent().getIntExtra("Street_ID", 0);
   db.openDataBase();

   Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id as _id, City_id, Street FROM Streets WHERE _id = '" +streetId+"'", null);

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        elevation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elevation);
        elevation.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Street_Id)));

        elevation1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elevation1);
        elevation1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Street")));
    }
```

Any help would be great!  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing. Are you trying to display the city *and* its streets in one ListView? That's going to be messy. As far as I can tell, you're doing it with an adapter that contains an array of cursors, and I'm not sure that will work.

Regardless, the parameter for onListItemClicked() that points to an item in the backing data is not *position* but *id*. Position is the index of the list item in the ListView; id is the _ID value of row in the Cursor (for cursor adapters) or the index of the data item in the
data. They can be different.

Next, you put the street ID in as the column index of the _id value in the cursor?! This makes no sense to me. In the next activity, you're not going to be selecting on street ID, you're going to be selecting on the index of the street ID *column* in the cursor.

I'd have to more about your database organization to give you any further direction. However, if I were implementing this, I'd display cities in one activity and streets in the next.

Answer (score 0):

A. Elk pointed out more than one issue with the organization of the activities, but one of those is easily solved: finding the record id (value contained in the '_id' column in the database) based on the cursor id. Here's how I did it:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        String recId = c.getString(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayRecordActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(RECORD_ID, recId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```